# Extract embedded script from web page

Tags: python, html, ajax, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have a link i want to scrape the content from that looks like this:

```
https://www.whatever.com/getDescModuleAjax.htm?productId=32663684002&t=1478698394335
```

But when i want to open it with selenium it won't work. When i load it in a normal Browser it opens as plain Text with the Html in a bracket like this:

```
window.productDescription='<div style="clea.... 
#I want this 
....n.jpg" width="950"/></p></div>'";
```

I was thinking i will Download the source code as plain text and extract the content i need using Bs4. But this can't be the best solution. is there a way to ignore the tags and load the web page  normally using selenium and python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the source code is inside of JS variable:
`window.variable="<div>...</div>"` then you probably can't use *bs4* to resolve it since bs4 works for pure html DOM nodes.

> Is there a way to ignore the tags and load the web page normally using selenium and python

Most likely Selenium should be able to force on-page JS to get executed and load variable content into page's DOM. Try to search where `window.productDescription` or `productDescription` expression is applied/used (in which onloaded `.js` files)?